# 2D Array's & Out of bounds exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

**I hate Arrays**

So I've been doing some coding and I've come up with an error (out of bounds exception) that I just can't seem to fix. I believe where I am saying 'array1[counter2][counter] = input2.nextLine();' is the problem but I don't know what is wrong! Help, I can't stand these Out of Bounds exceptions

The Idea for the program is an online phone book that you can add contacts, view them, and search by their first name, surname, and phone number.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.awt.*;
public class testMattWalker {
 //
 public static void main (String[] args){
   //Declare all your variables here. Make sure to provide a comment explaining the purpose of each variable
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
   int counter = 0;
   int counter2 = 0;
   boolean go = true;

   //Temp VAriables for entry 
   String firstNameOfEntry = "";
   String lastNameOfEntry = "";
   String personPhoneNumber = "";
   //

   //create array
   String [][] array1 = new String[5][3];

   while (go) {

   String choice = "";

   System.err.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDIDGITAL PHONE BOOK 2013");   
   System.out.println("1- Create phone book\n2- Display phone book\n3- Find person(s) by last name\n4- Find person(s) by first name\n5- Find person(s) by phone number\n6- Exit application");
   choice = input.nextLine(); 

   if (choice.equals("1") && counter2 != 6) {

     System.err.println("\n\n\n\n\nPHONE BOOK ENTRY CREATOR:");
     System.out.println("Please enter the first name of the person you wish to enter: ");
     array1[counter2][counter] = input2.nextLine();
     counter++;

     System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the person you wish to enter: ");
     array1[counter2][counter] = input3.nextLine();
     counter++;

     System.out.println("Please enter the phone number of this person: example:9057773344");
     array1[counter2][counter] = input4.nextLine();
     counter++;
     counter2++;

   }else if (choice.equals("2")) {



   }else if (choice.equals("3")) {



   }else if (choice.equals("4")) {



   }else if (choice.equals("5")) {



   }else if (choice.equals("6")) {

   }
   }
 }// end of main
}// end of class
```

I know it's not close to done but I'm the kind of guy who likes to fix everything before moving on so any help would be appreciated! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  set the second dimension of your array as 3, but in your code you add 1 to counter 3 times, meaning it goes out of bounds of the array after the first iteration of the code.

As ljgw said array indexes start at 0, so a dimension of 3 means the corresponding indexes are 0,1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that array indexes start with `0`. So: `5` is already out-of-bounds for counter2.